# Tengo problema con esta funcion, el cual es que no realiza la operacion sino que sale como resultado NaN

Tags: javascript

Tengo problema con esta funcion el cual es que no resuelve la operacion sino que sale como resultado NaN

```
var numero=prompt("Digite dos numero");
var numero= prompt("Digite otro numero");

function suma (num1, num2){

 var resultado = num1 + num2;
 console.log (resultado);

}

suma ();
```

Comment: ¿y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Debes parsearlos a entero antes de sumarlos  , por eso te arroja ```NaN``` significa not a number

Comment: intenta esto: ```parseInt(num1, 10)+parseInt(num2, 10)``` el 10 es la base decimal, prompt recoge strings es por eso el error

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 errores principales:

- No indicas que los valores ingresados los reconoca como números, motivo por el cual no hará la suma sino que los concatenará
- Tu segundo error es que cuando invocas a la función no le estas pasando como argumentos las variables que se supone representan a los 2 prompt que llevas a cabo, motivo por el cual dirá `NaN`
- Usa la función `Number()` para que el contenido de la variable sea interpretado del valor acorde

Entonces tu código:

```js
    var numero1=prompt("Digite dos numero");
    var numero2= prompt("Digite otro numero");
    
    function suma (num1, num2){
    
     var resultado = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
     console.log (resultado);
    
    }
    
    suma (numero1, numero2);
```

**Importante**

> Es decir le estás pasando los parámetros cuando construyes la función que le hace saber cuántos y que hará con dichos valores, pero cuando invocas a la función te está haciendo falta pasar los argumentos que para fines prácticos son las dos variables que guardan lo que recibe el prompt